# How to put Javascript code in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

In that project, i want to create two drop down lists(category, item). If i select one of the category named car, then item drop down list should have this. (Honda, Volvo, Nissan)

If i select one of the category named phone, then item drop down list should have this. (iPhone, Samsung, Nokia)
WORKING DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/r7MN9/3/ (with jquery)

```
cars = new Array("Mercedes", "Volvo", "BMW", "porche");
phones = new Array('Samsung', 'Nokia', 'Iphone');

populateSelect();

$(function () {

    $('#cat').change(function () {
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect() {
    cat = $('#cat').val();
    $('#item').html('');


    if (cat == 'car') {
        cars.forEach(function (t) {
            $('#item').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    }

    if (cat == 'phone') {
        phones.forEach(function (t) {
            $('#item').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    }

}
```

but i do not know how to connect html code with java code or jquery code?

Comment: There is no JAVA code ,its javascript

Comment: Your code is working fine ,What else is expected?

Comment: ooh, yes, please help me to link

Comment: @PatrickQ Sounds unclear to mee... ;-)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You connected HTML and javascript in the fiddle?  You have some HTML and some javascript - the only difference in reality is that the javascript needs to be in a `<script>` tag.  Can you clarify waht you can't do/need to know?

Comment: i must to write in html code, but i dont know Where to write javascripts code and use them?

Comment: javascript code is written in head tag / OR before body tag

Comment: See how HTML , Jscript gets engaged use the url http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_validate_email

Comment: yes, i  written in head tag in <script> tag, but don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to import the JQuery library with `<script>` tags like so :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you can put your script in between `<script>` tags, or create a separate .js file and import it the same way you imported the JQuery library.

### Option 1

save the file and import it like so

```
<script src="myFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### Option 2

put your code in between `<script>` tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
    phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');

    populateSelect();

    $(function() {

          $('#cat').change(function(){
            populateSelect();
        });

    });


    function populateSelect(){
        cat=$('#cat').val();
        $('#item').html('');


        if(cat=='car'){
            cars.forEach(function(t) { 
                $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
        }

        if(cat=='phone'){
            phones.forEach(function(t) {
                $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
        }

    } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in a .js and link it with:

```
<script src="yourCode.js"></script>
```

Or write your javascript code in the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Your javascript code here
</script>
```